# Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server

Why does this error happen: `Msg 512 .. Subquery returned more than 1 value` on this query?

```
update [MEDC_MDC].[dbo].[Readings] 
 set [AccountNo]  = 
(select site_identifier
from [MEDCBSQL01.EHC.COM.OM].[orion_ehc_medc].[dbo].[v_party_acct2] a 
Where active_meter_number in (select meterno from [MEDC_MDC].[dbo].[Readings]
where  service_type <> 'W' and accountno is null) )
where accountno is null
```

Comment: Like the error states, your SELECT (subquery) is returning more than one value.  You can't assign a single column in a single row more than a single value.  Modify your subquery so that it returns one unique value.

Comment: Rather than using a subquery, you might want to use the syntax `UPDATE {Alias} SET {Column} = {expression} FROM {Update Table} {Alias} JOIN {Other Table} ON {Expression}... [WHERE]`

Comment: You first need to think about *what it means* then you get more than one "hit" from the subquery. How do you want to handle that. Does it mean you have a problem in your data? Do you want to se the AccountNo column to *any* of the values that the subquery returns (which is what Larnu's and ikram's suggestions does)? Or do you prefer an error. Of do you have a logic flaw in how you think of and relate the data?

Comment: Basically I want to update the column **site_identifier** based on the value in **meterno** in the reading table. The site_identifier is available in different database

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that your subquery returns single value, so modify it and make sure that query returns single value.

One option is adding **TOP 1**:

```
update [MEDC_MDC].[dbo].[Readings] 
set [AccountNo]  = 
(select TOP 1 site_identifier
from [MEDCBSQL01.EHC.COM.OM].[orion_ehc_medc].[dbo].[v_party_acct2] a 
Where active_meter_number in (select meterno from [MEDC_MDC].[dbo].[Readings]
where  service_type <> 'W' and accountno is null) )
where accountno is null
```

Comment: dear Ikram thanks for your response. the Top 1 has updated all values with the same value of the first row. I still need an answer . thanks