# SQL Server Subquery Question and Explanation

Tags: sql-server

I have wrote the following report (I know there are other issues with it that needs resolving) however I have ran in to an error.

Please can you explain what this error means.

> SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Also where my mistakes are in this report to throw this error.

```
--SELECT Database Name
USE FEN;

--DECLARE Variables
DECLARE @Yesterday INT;
DECLARE @YesterdayLastYear INT;
DECLARE @YTD1 DECIMAL(10,2)
DECLARE @LastWeek INT;
DECLARE @LastWeekLastYear INT;
DECLARE @YTD2 DECIMAL (10,2);

-- SET Variables value with queries
SET @Yesterday = (SELECT SUM (ri.Sales_Quantity) FROM  ReportTransactions AS RT     LEFT JOIN ReportItems AS ri ON rt.Report_Transaction_ID = ri.Report_Transaction_ID      LEFT JOIN MMGroups AS mmg ON ri.MMGroup2_ID = MMG.ID    LEFT JOIN Locations AS L ON L.Location_ID = RT.Store_ID WHERE   rt.Transaction_Date > DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AND   (NULL IS NULL OR rt.Store_ID = NULL)   AND  (rt.Training_Mode IS NULL OR rt.Training_Mode = 0)   AND    ri.Item_Voided = 0   AND    ri.Void_Type = 0   AND  rt.Transaction_Type IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)   AND  ri.Item_Type IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 54, 55, 81, 84, 11, 12, 13, 22, 25, 27, 82) GROUP BY     RT.Store_ID,    L.Name, CASE WHEN ri.MMGroup2_ID IS NULL OR ri.MMGroup2_ID = '' THEN '99999' ELSE ri.MMGroup2_ID END,   CASE WHEN ri.MMGroup3_ID IS NULL OR ri.MMGroup3_ID = '' THEN '99999' ELSE ri.MMGroup3_ID END  );
SET @YesterdayLastYear = (SELECT SUM (ri.Sales_Quantity) FROM  ReportTransactions AS RT     LEFT JOIN ReportItems AS ri ON rt.Report_Transaction_ID = ri.Report_Transaction_ID      LEFT JOIN MMGroups AS mmg ON ri.MMGroup2_ID = MMG.ID    LEFT JOIN Locations AS L ON L.Location_ID = RT.Store_ID WHERE   rt.Transaction_Date > CONVERT(DateTime, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()))) AND rt.Transaction_Date < DATEADD(hour, 23, DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0, DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())))) AND   (NULL IS NULL OR rt.Store_ID = NULL)   AND  (rt.Training_Mode IS NULL OR rt.Training_Mode = 0)   AND    ri.Item_Voided = 0   AND    ri.Void_Type = 0   AND  rt.Transaction_Type IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)   AND  ri.Item_Type IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 54, 55, 81, 84, 11, 12, 13, 22, 25, 27, 82) GROUP BY     RT.Store_ID,    L.Name, CASE WHEN ri.MMGroup2_ID IS NULL OR ri.MMGroup2_ID = '' THEN '99999' ELSE ri.MMGroup2_ID END,   CASE WHEN ri.MMGroup3_ID IS NULL OR ri.MMGroup3_ID = '' THEN '99999' ELSE ri.MMGroup3_ID END  );
SET @YTD1 = (SELECT  CAST(@Yesterday AS FLOAT)/CAST(@YesterdayLastYear AS FLOAT) * 100);
SET @LastWeek = (SELECT SUM(ri.Sales_Quantity) FROM  ReportTransactions AS RT   LEFT JOIN ReportItems AS ri ON rt.Report_Transaction_ID = ri.Report_Transaction_ID      LEFT JOIN MMGroups AS mmg ON ri.MMGroup2_ID = MMG.ID    LEFT JOIN Locations AS L ON L.Location_ID = RT.Store_ID WHERE   rt.Transaction_Date BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()) AND  (NULL IS NULL OR rt.Store_ID = NULL)   AND  (rt.Training_Mode IS NULL OR rt.Training_Mode = 0)   AND    ri.Item_Voided = 0   AND    ri.Void_Type = 0   AND  rt.Transaction_Type IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)   AND  ri.Item_Type IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 54, 55, 81, 84, 11, 12, 13, 22, 25, 27, 82) GROUP BY     RT.Store_ID,    L.Name, CASE WHEN ri.MMGroup2_ID IS NULL OR ri.MMGroup2_ID = '' THEN '99999' ELSE ri.MMGroup2_ID END,   CASE WHEN ri.MMGroup3_ID IS NULL OR ri.MMGroup3_ID = '' THEN '99999' ELSE ri.MMGroup3_ID END);
SET @LastWeekLastYear = 1000;
SET @YTD2 = (SELECT CAST(@LastWeek AS FLOAT)/CAST(@LastWeekLastYear AS FLOAT) * 100)

--SELECT report columns 
SELECT 
    RT.Store_ID,
    L.Name,
    (SELECT @Yesterday) AS 'Sales Day £',   
    (SELECT @YesterdayLastYear) AS 'VAR Vs LY £',
    (SELECT @YTD1) AS 'VAR Vs LY %',
    (SELECT @LastWeek) AS 'Sales Week to Date £',
    (SELECT @LastWeekLastYear) AS 'VAR Vs LY £k',
    (SELECT @YTD2)  AS 'VAR Vs LY %'
--From Required Tables and Joins    
FROM ReportTransactions AS RT 
    LEFT JOIN ReportItems AS ri ON rt.Report_Transaction_ID = ri.Report_Transaction_ID  
    LEFT JOIN MMGroups AS mmg ON ri.MMGroup2_ID = MMG.ID
    LEFT JOIN Locations AS L ON L.Location_ID = RT.Store_ID      
-- Group by Store Number and Name 
GROUP BY 
    RT.Store_ID,
    L.Name
```

Comment: This error is asked almost EVERY DAY - and the solution is the same. You have an expression that should return a single (1 row, 1 column) value but does not. Learn to debug your own code. Take the above, comment out everything after the first set statement. Run it. If success, uncommment the next statement. Repeat. Your first problem is the second set statement.

Comment: And there are likely many more issues that need to be addressed. All those outer joins are highly, HIGHLY suspicious.

Comment: @SMor I appreciate the time you took to reply. I am in over my head here with this SQL I will admit and it was kind of just dropped on me to work out. I am trying my best to resolve the issues. Thanks

Comment: The problem is going to be in one of the `SET @variable` commands.   Run each of them individually until you find which one is causing the error.

Comment: You do NOT need to use a subquery every time you reference a variable. And for heavens sake do yourself a favor and format those queries. Reading queries that are hundreds of characters long on a single line makes me want to slit my own throat. You have group bys in some of those queries which is where the error comes from but this really needs some more help.

Comment: Duplicate of [Msg 512, Level 16, State 1,Subquery returned more than 1 value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516291) or [Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1 value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52853761) or [Error: “SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=” when I execute procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53391233)?

Comment: @TabAlleman thanks I have resolved the issue and working on better formatting. I am newish to be SQL queries like this and learning a lot and fast but I am as you can see a novice due to my code. However I have learned better debugging techniques today.